# Command line not working?

Tags: installation, mount, hard-drive, macbook

So, I just installed Ubuntu on my Macbook pro (dual-boot) and I noticed that I couldn't see my other Hard Drive (I partitioned ~40gb just for Ubuntu, but I obviously don't want to install programs on that).

So I opened up the command console and typed "sudo fdisk -l". I got "invalid option-- '1'" when doing this. Am I doing something wrong? It won't let me list my drives as apparently that isn't a real option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you typed sudo fdisk -l (letter L) rather than sudo fdisk -1 (number one). The error message indicates that it was a one rather than an L.